# jQuery: how can I add helpful information to my page elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tempted to make some custom attributes for some page elements to make selection easier, via the `.attr();` function in jQuery.

I figure that this is probably discouraged, as there is a lot of flexibility in jQuery and javaScript that, as a novice, I have not learned to employ yet to its full potential.

Other than making cryptic IDs or adding lots of classes, what are some ways to add more information to my divs and other page elements for easy selecting via the selector `$()`?

I'm mostly curious as to pros/cons, and what memory issues or speed issues result based on different approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a problem at all creating custom attributes on your elements. Anyway, you should follow the `html5 data-` spec.

```
<div id="foo" data-info="hello" data-more="{'iam': 'anobject'}" />
```

The cool thing about using this is, jQuery (latest version) will automatically parse the `data-x` attributes and adds those into the `.data()` expando.

```
$('#foo').data('info') === 'hello'
$('#foo').data('more').iam === 'anobject'
```

You are still able to run a selector like

```
$('div[data-info=hello]')
```

on your elements.

ref.: [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), [html5 data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Comment: Will this cause XHTML strict not to validate? I'm not discouraging this as a solution; I'm simply curious.

Comment: Pardon the nubery, but how would I select all elements with a matching data-info attribute?

Comment: @nalroff: it probably will fail HTML4 validation. But seriously, who really cares on that context.

Comment: @sova: Normal attribute selector: `$(*[data-info=something])`

Comment: @sova: you should be able to take a standard selector (even $(*) if need be) and tack on the ".data()" piece. So if it's divs you want, you'd say '$("div").data('info')'.

Comment: @nalroff: No, this would return the value of `info` for the first of the selected elements.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 introduces [`data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). So if you are going to introduce custom attributes, I would at least stick to this specification.

There is also the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method in jQuery for associating arbitrary data with elements. As long as you don't need to use the data  in a selector, this is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery plug ins usually use some already existing attributes like "rel" or "title" but jQuery also has the `.data()` method which stores information on an specific object in javascript. It acts like a log.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Both of this techniques are acceptable and work well.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to be aware of is that the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) are *extremely* powerful. You don't always need to select by an ID or a class - you can select by tag, by type, by relation to another selection (children/parents/siblings/etc). So, there may not be a need to add IDs or classes to your various elements in order to select them.

With that said, don't avoid classes and IDs just for avoiding classes and IDs. They exist for a reason, and that reason is to make selection of them straightforward and easy (whether it is with jQuery or CSS or whatever else). If you remove classes and IDs, you may make your HTML look nicer, but your jQuery code may become convoluted and/or very inefficient. (For example, it is always faster to select an ID directly than select a parent component and find its children.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be discouraged to use attr(). It is a powerfull tool and really helps to add more information to your elements. I have some projects using it to suport internal javascript frameworks and it turns my code clean and legible. And it has the advantage to be is a ease to work with selectors!

Comment: thank you for your kind words =)  .attr() is arguably very awesome, I'm glad its flexibility is not limited to the standard attributes!

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using only classes and IDs for the initial selection but here are some handy selectors you can use on top of this:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

A unique ID is the quickest way to find an element through jQuery, so if the purpose of your temptation is to make your elements easier for jQuery to retrieve, it seems pointless.

I've used such techniques for adding attributes such as title or alt for better accessibility.

Comment: I guess I meant that I am not trying to retrieve just one element with a unique ID, I have various groupings of elements and making my own attributes would help in this case I believe

Comment: Yup, but still in that case I'd say classes would do the job perfectly. But as mentioned by amosrivera data() can be a solution as it can also filter jQuery objects .filter("data='whatever'")

Answer (score 0):

Use `.data('key', 'val')` to set your data and`.data('key')` to read it.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use the Data api (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)